# How to send emails by dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm looking for a way to send email through dialogflow with the information the bot gets from the user, for example: full name, email, etc.

I've already researched a lot and saw that there is a way using nodemailer, but I could not make it work.

Comment: It's really difficult to help without more info on what you've tried. Can you share the code showing what you've done?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the mail in your fulfillment code at your backbend. You just need to "Enable webhook call for this intent" in the "Fulfillment" section of your Intent. Dialogflow itself has no support to send mails. You need to implement that yourself e.g. with the npm package you found.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Botonic](https://github.com/hubtype/botonic) could be useful in this case. It's an open-source framework to create bots with React and it has a [Dialogflow plugin](https://botonic.io/docs/plugins/plugin-dialogflow) to manage NLU stuff.